# create table with rows and columns (full box) in c++

Tags: c++

i want to create a table with has box for each house members table. i use here a 2D array for member and use some ascii character like '|','-' for rows and columns and its create with loops ,, but i have a problem ,,, the boxes doesn't complete good , the left column of box doesn't complete and there is a "endl" in program with i can't find it and remove it to fix my table style . please run my program on your compiler to undrestand better you can see the picture

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

void setTable();
string table[10][2] = {
    // array
    {" black", " 0"},  {" brown", " 1"}, {" red", " 2"},  {" orange", " 3"},
    {" yellow", " 4"}, {" green", " 5"}, {" blue", " 6"}, {" violet", " 7"},
    {" gray", " 8"},   {" white", " 9"},
};
int main() {
  setTable();

  getch();
  return 0;
}
void setTable() {
  char row = 205, col = 179, cornerL = 198, cornerR = 181, midd = 197,
       cornerLU = 218;
  char cornerRU = 188, middU = 193, cornerRR = 191, cornerLL = 218,
       middleSingle = 194;  // ascii codes

  for (int f = 0; f < 17; f++) {
    if (f == 0) {
      cout << cornerLL;
    } else if (f == 16) {
      cout << cornerRR;
    } else if (f == 8) {
      cout << middleSingle;
    } else {
      cout << row;
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << "\n";
    for (int r = 0; r < 16; r++) {
      if (r == 0)
        cout << col;
      else if (r == 14)
        cout << col;
      else if (r == 7)
        cout << col;  // midd
      cout << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      cout << table[i][j] << "\t";
      cout << col;
    }
    cout << "\n";
    for (int rd = 0; rd < 17; rd++) {
      switch (rd) {
        case 0:
          cout << cornerL;
          continue;
        case 16:
          cout << cornerR;
          continue;
        case 8:
          cout << midd;
          continue;
        default:
          cout << row;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of us running the program ourselves, or following an external link, it would be preferable if you added the output as text. Also, show the output that you expect.

Comment: i want that output be like a table that has complate BORDERs around each house of table (look at output picture )the left borders are not complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this !

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <windows.h>
 #include <string.h>
 using namespace std;

void setTable();
string table[10][2] = {  { "black", " 0" },  { "brown", " 1" },  { "red", " 2" },
  { "orange", " 3" },  { "yellow", " 4" },  { "green", " 5" },  { "blue", " 6" },
  { "violet", " 7" },  { "gray", " 8" },  { "white", " 9" } };
   
int main() {
    setTable();
    getch();
    return 0;
} 
void setTable()    {
    char row = 205, col = 179, cornerL = 198, cornerR = 181, midd = 197, cornerLU = 218;
    char cornerRU = 188, middU = 193, cornerRR = 191, cornerLL = 218, middleSingle = 194; //ascii codes

    for (int f = 0; f < 17; f++) {
      if (f == 0) {  cout << cornerLL;    }
      else if (f == 16) {  cout << cornerRR;   }
      else if (f == 8) {cout << middleSingle;      }
      else {  cout << row;      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    /****   cout << "\n";
        for (int r = 0; r < 16; r++) {
           if (r == 0)  cout << col;
           else if (r == 14)  cout << col;
           else if (r == 7)   cout << col; // midd
           cout << " ";
        }*****/

        cout << "\n";
        cout << col;            
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
           cout << table[i][j] << "\t";
           cout << col;
        }
        cout << "\n";
        for (int rd = 0; rd < 17; rd++) {
            switch (rd) {
                case 0: cout << cornerL;continue;
                case 16: cout << cornerR; continue;
                 case 8: cout << midd;   continue;
                default:cout << row;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1- I Changed every " black" into "black" pb with over tab size.
2- I Added a starting col : cout << col;
3- I commented empty line

With my charset the result is :

```
┌═══════┬═══════┐
│black  │ 0     │
ã═══════┼═══════Á
│brown  │ 1     │
ã═══════┼═══════Á
│red    │ 2     │
ã═══════┼═══════Á
│orange │ 3     │
ã═══════┼═══════Á
│yellow │ 4     │
ã═══════┼═══════Á
│green  │ 5     │
ã═══════┼═══════Á
│blue   │ 6     │
ã═══════┼═══════Á
│violet │ 7     │
ã═══════┼═══════Á
│gray   │ 8     │
ã═══════┼═══════Á
│white  │ 9     │
ã═══════┼═══════Á
```

Comment: thanks for your help ;     have you any idea about end of the table? , i mean the last borders are have to change to another ascii code to be better style (the border after last array (white | 9 ) )

Comment: For the last border, you can test the last row index and then print the specific border.